# Динамический baseUrl Retrofit & Dagger2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rest

Приложение - клиент для информационной системы, рассчитанной на большое количество организаций (более 2000).
Для каждой из организаций используется свой URL вида:

- subdomain1.domain.com
- subdomain2.domain.com
- subdomain3.domain.com

Структура файлов у всех идентична.

Например:

@GET("login") @GET("notice") @GET("events")  и т.д.

Как, используя связку Retrofit & Dagger2, динамически изменять baseUrl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для динамического изменения `baseUrl` в Retrofit необходимо передавать в него не захардкоженный url, а реализацию интерфейса `BaseUrl`

```
public class UrlProvider implements BaseUrl {

    private HttpUrl httpUrl;

    public UrlProvider(String url) {
        //передаем стандартный урл
        httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse(url);
    }

    // вызываем когда необходимо изменить урл
    public void changeUrl(@NonNull String url) {
        httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse(url);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpUrl url() {
        return httpUrl;
    }
}
```

Ну а в модуле для Daggera делаете примерно так

```
@Provides
@Singleton
UrlProvider urlProvider(PrefWrapper prefWrapper){
    return new UrlProvider(prefWrapper.getPref().url());
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(UrlProvider urlProvider){
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            //прочие настройки 
            .baseUrl(urlProvider)
            .build();
}
```

Если потребуется изменить url, то просто запросите у даггера зависимость `UrlProvider`, и установите ей новый `URL`

`PrefWrapper` в данном случае является оберткой вокруг `SharedPreference` в которой хранится текущий URL. Вы можете использовать что-то свое.

Comment: Я только начинаю работать с DI и мне явно не хватает понимания основ. Спасибо, Вам огромное за развернутый ответ!